# mysql query where select produces an array

Tags: mysql

The following query fails as the select statement in the where condition produces an array of id's.
Im relatively new to using sql so any help on how to rectify would be appreciated.

```
    SELECT sum(txnpnl) FROM tdmarketprob.pnl_transactions
    WHERE instrumentid = (SELECT instrumentid
    FROM tdmarketprob.pnl_instruments
    WHERE symbol="ES") and txnpnl <>0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `SELECT sum(txnpnl) FROM tdmarketprob.pnl_transactions
    WHERE instrumentid IN (SELECT instrumentid
    FROM tdmarketprob.pnl_instruments
    WHERE symbol="ES") and txnpnl <>0;`

Answer (score 0):

You better use a join than a nested query. Like this :

```
SELECT sum(t.txnpnl) FROM tdmarketprob.pnl_transactions t
inner join tdmarketprob.pnl_instruments i
on t. instrumentid = t. instrumentid
WHERE i.symbol="ES" and t.txnpnl <>0;
```

You are not specific enough on what result you like to get, so I'm not sure if this answer is sufficient.